# How to get global 2d array of pointers in a function with populated values?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, recursion

How to get a array of pointers(declared as global) in a function from another function which dynamically defines the array and populates it's elements??

```
    int row=0, col=0, special=0;
    int **maze,*exact;


    void func(int n, int m, int a){
        if(n==0 && m==0)
            a=0;
        if(maze[n][m]==1)
            a++;
        if(n==row-1 && m==col-1){
            exact[a]++;
            return;
        }
        if(m<col-1)
            func(n,m+1,a);
        if(n<row-1)
            func(n+1,m,a);
    }


    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        int a=0,b=0;
        scanf("%d%d%d",&row,&col,&special);
        *maze = new int[row];
        for(int i = 0; i<row;i++)
            maze[i] = new int[col];
        exact = new int[special+1];
        fill(&maze[0][0],&maze[0][0]+sizeof(maze),0);
        fill(exact,exact+special+1,0);
        for(int i = 0; i<special;i++){
            scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b);
            maze[a--][b--]=1;
        }
        func(0,0,0);
        for(int i = 0; i<=special;i++){
            printf("%d\t",exact[i]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

This code doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: How is it not working, exactly? What should this be doing, and what errors do you get instead?

Comment: That said, your initialization of maze should not work, since it should be an int** and you derefernce it before it’s initialized, then initialize it to the wrong type.

Comment: So, what changes should I make, I first set the number of rows to #row and then iterated over the rows to create columns of size #columns...

Comment: One approach is to declare `int *maze;` and initialize it with `new int[row][columns];`You can pass a function the arguments `void f(size_t row, size_t columns, maze[row][columns])`. Note that the type will implicitly convert to `int*`, not `int**`. Another is to initialize `maze` to an array of `int[ row]` and then each row to an array of `int[columns]`, but you generally would only do this to save space if the array is not rectangular.  Otherwise, the first approach is more efficient.